# Not able to hibernate or suspend centos system

Tags: centos, sleep

I am running Centos 7 and all I want to do is make my computer go to sleep immediately. There is a setting I have set to make my computer go to sleep but only after a certain amount of inactivity but when I leave work, I want to be able to make it go to sleep immediately right after instead of turning my computer off.

I looked and found this link
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-to-suspend-hibernate-laptop-netbook-pc/
and I tried both commands

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

and

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

and get the message

```
A dependency job for suspend.target failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

I just want to be able to make my computer go to sleep so that I can pick up from where I left off the day before instead of turning off my computer everytime I leave from work.

Comment: So did you look at `journalctl -xe` for details? Also look in the logs like dmesg/var/log/syslog/etc. "systemctl suspend" works on most machines so something is probably wrong with the current setup but we don't know what. Also a lot of distros will suspend the computer when you press the power button though this is highly dependent on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have either the **pm-suspend** or **pm-hibernate** programs installed? These tools work independently of systemd, and thus would not be affected by systemd's problem. You can get both of these tools from the package **pm-utils**, although IDK if that package is available  on CentOS (it's not in Fedora), so you might have to build it from source. You can get it from this git repo: git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pm-utils

You could also try install the **uswusp** package, although that might not be available in CenOS's repos, either. If you install this, you can use **s2disk** to hibernate, and **s2ram** to suspend to ram. You can get this program [from Sourceforge](http://suspend.sourceforge.net/).

A third option is to tell the system to suspend directly, without calling a specific program. This can be done by overwriting the **/sys/power/state** file with with "disk" to hibernate, or with "mem" to suspend. Do note that this file can only be modified by root. You could overwrite it by doing something like `sudo sh -c 'printf mem > /sys/power/state'`, or `echo disk | sudo dd status=none of=/sys/power/state`.